# Center UITableView on iPad by adding a margin via contentInset property?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I want to reuse an iPhone's UITableView on the iPad by adding a left/right margin thereby centering it. I tried using the `.contentInset` property, but it didn't seem to affect the right margin. Am I missing something? *(I tried a negative right-inset right that didn't work either.)*

*([Here is a gist with test code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/003e57bf021dbca09924) that you can throw into a UITableViewController subclass.)*

```
// In a UITableViewController subclass
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // the space I want on either side of the table
    CGFloat xMargin = 100.0f;

    // increase content inset and decrease content size an equal amount
    UIEdgeInsets contentInset = self.tableView.contentInset;
    contentInset.left = xMargin;
    contentInset.right = xMargin;
    CGSize contentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
    contentSize.width = contentSize.width -= xMargin * 2;

    self.tableView.contentSize = contentSize;
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInset;

    // Turning autolayout off doesn't appear to help
    //self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}
```

I can't just shorten the width of the table or the right margin won't have the right color or scroll the table in response to user touches.

[image: Tables]

Comment: Hmm for something like this the first thing I would try is instead of using a UITableViewController, I'd use a normal UIViewController and add the UITableView as a subview.  You should easily be able to set it's frame to your liking without the background issues

Comment: @user2608440 I tried that. (I used UITableViewController to make the example code simpler.) It's true I can easily set the frame of the tableview, but that doesn't solve my problem – the area on the sides wouldn't be part of the tableView and therefore not scrollable, as my desired screenshot implies.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  What about creating a custom UITableViewCell to achieve the look?  It could still span the whole width of the screen, but each cell would have a white subview centered on it with the "margins" being either transparent or the same grey color.

Comment: That might work. I was really hoping to avoid using a custom UITableViewCell subclass, though. (I want to use this layout throughout my app and I'd prefer to use stock UITableViewCell.) And other ideas?

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is using a gesture recognizer on the whole view to map to the tableView.  But going that route seems to be more complicated for reuse across all your other views.  For reuse, I personally would use normal UIViewControllers and subclass a UITableView which uses the custom cell.  This way the only thing you'd need to do on each VC is add the custom UITableView as a subview and change the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only centering you're worried about you can center a view inside its parent view by using:

```
childView.center = [parent convertPoint:parent.center fromView:parent.superview];
```

`contentInset` doesn't change the size of the view, it simply adds to the scrolling area around the content.

Comment: I want it to have a smaller width and (still) be centered -- like having an iPhone-width table on an iPad.

Comment: In that case edit the tableView's `frame` property to change it's size and use the above line of code to center it.

Comment: If I just shorten `tableView.frame.size.width` it will make the margin area not share the table's backgroundColor and the user won't be able to use that area to scroll.

Comment: Aha, in that case have you looked at the `contentSize` property?

Comment: I think I should be able to reduce the contentSize.width and increase the contentInset.left/right an equivalent amount to get the effect I desire... but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Have you got autolayout set for this view controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57699/discussion-between-zekel-and-kerrm).

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to subclass `UITableViewCell` like so:

.h file:

```
@interface AGBTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat minimumWidth;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation AGBTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.minimumWidth = 320;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    CGRect newFrame = frame;

    if (CGRectGetWidth(newFrame) > self.minimumWidth) {
        CGFloat margin = (CGRectGetWidth(newFrame) - self.minimumWidth) / 2;
        newFrame.origin.x = margin;
        newFrame.size.width = self.minimumWidth;
    }

    [super setFrame:newFrame];
}

@end
```

The cells will be inset, but you'll still be able to scroll on the sides:

[image]

[Sample project here](http://cl.ly/0X3V002i182y).

This approach will need some extra work to handle table animations like deleting rows.

Comment: I've used your approach, but as you said animating rows doesn't work pretty well, any suggestions?